# echoing out sql data in a php table

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a database in SQL, and I am trying to echo the data in an HTML table. I have created a separate PHP file that will reference specific criteria (in this case, industries), that determine which records appear in the table.

My code is fetching all the matching the criteria but displaying only the first result in a table. All the other results are just only written without space in betweem them. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

```
mysql_select_db("project") or die(mysql_error());
print ("<h1>Database</h1>");
print("</br>");
print("</br>");


if($industry == "Media")
    {
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE industry = 'Media' ";
        $data = count($id);             

        } elseif ($industry == "Finance")
    {
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE industry = 'Finance' ";               

    } elseif ($industry == "Technology")
    {
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE industry = 'Technology' ";                

    } elseif ($industry == "Health")
    {
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE industry = 'Health care/biotechnology' ";             

    } elseif ($industry == "RealEstate")
    {
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE industry = 'Real Estate' ";               

    } elseif ($industry == "Retail")
    {
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE industry = 'Retail' ";                

    } elseif ($industry == "Other")
    {
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE industry = 'Other' ";             

    } elseif ($industry == "Technology")
    {
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE industry = 'Technology' ";                

    } 
    ?>

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
    <th>Column 6</th>
</tr>
<?php
$id = $row['id'];
$firstName = $row['firstName'];
$lastName = $row['lastName'];
$company = $row['company'];
$totaldollar = $row['totaldollar'];
$formatted_dollar = number_format($totaldollar);

$dollar2 = $row['dollar2'];
$formatted_dollar2 = number_format($dollar2);

$year = $row['year'];
$industry = $row['industry'];


?>


<?php 
for($i = 0; $i < count($id); $i++)
{
 echo "<tr><td>" . $firstName . "</td><td>" . $lastName . "</td><td>" . $company . "</td><td>" . "$" . $formatted_dollar . "</td><td>" . "$" . $formatted_dollar2 . "</td><td>" . $industry . "</td></tr>" ;

}
?>    



</table>

  <?php

}

mysql_close($link);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are instigating `$row`. But, since it looks like your are treating `$id` as an array - `$i < count($id)`, then you probably want to set them as arrays -

```
<?php
    $id[] = $row['id'];
    $firstName[] = $row['firstName'];
    $lastName[] = $row['lastName'];
    $company[] = $row['company'];
    $totaldollar[] = $row['totaldollar'];
    $formatted_dollar[] = number_format($totaldollar);

    $dollar2[] = $row['dollar2'];
    $formatted_dollar2[] = number_format($dollar2);

    $year[] = $row['year'];
    $industry[] = $row['industry'];  
?>
```

Then in your loop, you need to use the `$i` to set the array key

```
<?php 
    for($i = 0; $i < count($id); $i++)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $firstName[$i] . "</td><td>" . $lastName[$i] . "</td><td>" . $company[$i] . "</td><td>" . "$" . $formatted_dollar[$i] . "</td><td>" . "$" . $formatted_dollar2[$i] . "</td><td>" . $industry[$i] . "</td></tr>" ;

}
?>
```

Comment: Hey Sean, Thanks for looking into this. I tried doing what you suggested, and now it's not displaying any of the data. Any other suggestions?

Comment: not without seeing your code. I don't know how you are instigating `$row`. Your code is missing a `mysql_query()` and a `mysql_fetch_*()`, so I don't know how you are getting your data.